Long npm response time
Whenever I use npm, whether I use npm run build or npm --version, it hangs on my terminal for a long time. It's kind of inconsistent how long I have to wait, but the response is never immediate. I've honestly waited 30 minutes before and it still won't load.
Below is an example of npm --version, and my terminal hanging on the command:
npm --version eliciting no response in the terminal
